# Laravel Eloquent combine Model::forceCreate and Model::firstOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

With Laravel & Eloquent, I'd like to :

- Create a model, *unless it already exists into the database* (like `Model::firstOrCreate` allows)
- At the same time, pass it a few attributes, including some which are *not listed in the `$fillable` array* of the model (like `Model::forceCreate` allows).

But how do I combine the capacities of `firstOrCreate` and `forceCreate`? Apparently, `Model::forceFirstOrCreate` doesn't exist!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [the `unguarded` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2204-L2223):

```php
$model = Model::unguarded(function() {
    return Model::firstOrCreate($attributes);
});
```

Comment: Great. Just as a matter of curiosity : is Model "re-guarded" at the end of the closure ?

Comment: It sure is. That's the whole point of this method. Check out the source; I linked to it in my answer.